# How to fetch value from the array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to fetch the value from the following

`Contact:{Id=0032800000RfjfMAAR, FirstName=xyz, password__c=abc}`

for example i want the value of `FirstName` from this.
 Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: What have you tried to do, and what does not working? SO is **NOT** a place for asking people to do yout work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you provide a the result of a `toString`method. 
If you have an instance of Class `Contact`, look a it closer, I bet you have at least 3 variables and you certainly have some method like `getFirstName` that could provide you the expected value as String.

But it has nothing to do with array.